# webdriverio 5.16 browser.element is not a function

Tags: node.js, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

i have a problem after i upgraded webdriver from 4.8 to 5.16:

My package.json

```
    "@wdio/cli": "^5.16.15",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.16.15",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^5.16.15",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^5.16.11",
    "@wdio/sync": "^5.16.15",
    ...
    "chromedriver": "^79.0.0",
    ...
    "selenium-webdriver": "3.0.0-beta-2",
    ....
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^5.0.2",
    "webdriverio": "^5.16.15",
```

then in my test i call:

```
browser.element('body')
```

result error:

```
browser.element is not a function
```

Was this function replaced (didn't find any notes about that)? and if so, whats the function to use now?
Or is there another problem? Help pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly, `browser.element()` is no longer available in v5.

As per their official changelog, it is changed to `browser.findElement` in v5.

You can also use `browser.$()` in place of `browser.element()`.

Here is the complete list of changes in v5 if you have not figured it out yet.

https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v500-2018-12-20

Answer (score 1):

`browser.elements(...)` no longer exists in v5.x - https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#boom-breaking-change-1

Just use

```
const elem = $('body')
```

to find first element, or

```
const divs = $$('div')
```

to find all elements, and get them in array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get an array of the elements then you need

`browser.elements('body') // plural`

for single element just use

`$('body')`

Hope I got the idea right